# incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p10le' for codec libx265

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am using

```
ffmpeg -probesize 2G -i input.ts -c:v libx265 -pix_fmt yuv420p10le -x265-params fps=50 -c:a libfdk_aac -t 00:00:05 /output.ts
```

I receive the error

```
incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p10le' for codec libx265m, auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
```

I am trying to create a UHD video with 10bit color depth from a UHD video with yuv420 pixel format

Any ideas?

```
ffmpeg version 2.5.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
built on Jan 19 2015 10:40:37 with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.54) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.5.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads -- 
enable-gpl 
--enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-   
ldflags= --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-  
libfreetype --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-ffplay --enable-libfdk-
aac --enable-libopus --enable-libquvi --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-vda


libavutil      54. 15.100 / 54. 15.100
libavcodec     56. 13.100 / 56. 13.100
libavformat    56. 15.102 / 56. 15.102
libavdevice    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
libavfilter     5.  2.103 /  5.  2.103
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100

Input #0, mpegts, from '/users/user/Documents/Capture4_HEVC_25M.ts':
Duration: 00:11:23.50, start: 2.000000, bitrate: 27892 kb/s
Program 1 
Stream #0:0[0x1e1]: Video: hevc (Main) ([36][0][0][0] / 0x0024), yuv420p(tv), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1   
DAR 16:9], 50 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x1e2](und): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 129  
kb/s
File '/Users/user/documents/4k_h265_50fps_10bit.ts' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] 
Incompatible pixel format 'yuv420p10le' for codec 'libx265', auto-selecting format 'yuv420p'
x265 [info]: HEVC encoder version 1.4
x265 [info]: build info [Mac OS X][clang 6.0.0][64 bit] 8bpp
x265 [info]: using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2
x265 [info]: Main profile, Level-5.1 (Main tier)
x265 [info]: WPP streams / frame threads / pool  : 34 / 2 / 4
x265 [info]: CTU size / RQT depth inter / intra  : 64 / 1 / 1
x265 [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 2
x265 [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut       : 25 / 250 / 40
x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2
x265 [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb / refs: 1 / 1 / 0 / 3
x265 [info]: Rate Control / AQ-Strength / CUTree : CRF-28.0 / 1.0 / 1
x265 [info]: tools: rd=3 lft sao signhide tmvp 
Output #0, mpegts, to '/Users/user/documents/4k_h265_50fps_10bit.ts':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf56.15.102
Stream #0:0: Video: hevc (libx265), yuv420p, 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 50 fps, 90k   
tbn, 50 tbc
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libx265
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (libfdk_aac), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 139 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc56.13.100 libfdk_aac
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (hevc (native) -> hevc (libx265))
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (libfdk_aac))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your x265 encoder is only built with 8bpp support:

```
build info [Mac OS X][clang 6.0.0][64 bit] 8bpp
```

You have to get a recent x265 with high bit depth support. Since you're using macOS, I'd do it with [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). Use `reinstall` instead of `install` if you already installed x265/ffmpeg with Homebrew before:

```
brew install x265
```

Then, I'd reinstall ffmpeg:

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Comment: I believe this has worked. Thank you so much!